# Discrete Mathematics Sets Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi i'm having difficulties working this question out I found, any help would be appreciated :)

Let $A = \{1,2,4\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3\}$. Define the function $f: A\to B$ by the rule.

What is the image of $3$?

What is the codomain of $f$?

Draw the digraph representing $f$

Is the function injective? Is the function surjective?

Comment: What is the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of $3$ is the "shadow" that the action "3" casts. Think of an image as being the result of an action. Similarly, the image is the result of the function. For example, if $f: x \to y = x^2$, then $f(2) = 4$, so $4$ is the image of $2$ due to the action (function) $f$.

The co-domain is the set that $x$ is mapped to.

The range, though, is what $x$ is actually mapped to. (What's the difference?)

The digraph (directed graph) is just the directed connection from $x$ to its image.

Functions are surjective if the co-domain is equal to the range. (see my above question about what is different from the range and co-domain.) The function is injective if for every image, there is only one pre-image mapped to it.